# Display 2 DIVs in same line where one is picture

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs, one should be on left side and the other on right side but in same line.

Behind I want to have parent div (#author-box) with grey background that will have height depending on the right div text height, so when you change devices if author-txt goes below author-img the gray background should be behind both of the divs.

I tried float left but then the gray background is really small and doesn't follow author-txt and author-img height.

Also I tried display:inline, but then text starts from the lower part of the image.

```
<div id="author-box">
  <div class="author-img"><img src="img.jpg" width="150px" height="149px" /></div>
  <div class="author-txt"><strong>About the author</strong><br/>author text<br/><strong>Connect with me:</strong> <a href="#">FaceBook</a> | <a href="#" target="_blank">LinedIn</a> | <a href="#">Twitter</a></div>
</div>

 #author-box {
 background-color: #ECECEC;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 font-size: 15px;
 padding: 10px;
 }
 .author-img{}
 .author-img img{
 border-radius: 100px;
 }
 .author-txt{}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple: (there are many other ways too)

```
.author-img {
    display:inline-block;
}

.author-txt {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/sem3qyyo/

If you want to use `float`ing, you will need to "clear" the container:

```
#author-box:after { /* just one method of clearing, there are others too */
    display:table;
    clear: both;
    content:" ";
}
.author-img {
    float:left;
}

.author-txt {
    float:left;
}
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/sem3qyyo/1/

Or use `float`ing and `overflow: auto;` on the container if your design allows it:

```
#author-box:after {
    overflow: auto; /* add this */
    background-color: #ECECEC;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.author-img {
    float:left;
}

.author-txt {
    float:left;
}
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/sem3qyyo/2/

And this can go on!

Comment: +1 Thinking of all `other ways` often prevents me from posting an answer.

Comment: @user2080812 You are welcome! Glad to be of help to you.